# Как получить доступ к textBox1 в классе WinForms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab_Work_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "****Fun With Class Types****" + "\r\n";
            Car myCar = new Car();
            myCar.petName = "Henry";
            myCar.currSpeed = 10;

            for (int i = 0; 1 <= 10; i++)
            {
                myCar.SpeedUp(5);
                myCar.PrintState();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class Car

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Lab_Work_1
{
    
    class Car    
    {
        
        public string petName;
        public int currSpeed;


        public void PrintState()
        {
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString("{0} is going {1}MPH. " + petName + currSpeed + "\r\n");
        }
      
        public void SpeedUp(int delta)
        {
            currSpeed += delta;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `1 <= 10` бесконечный цикл --> `i <= 10`

Comment: И смешно и плакать хочется) Не заметил . Спасибо большое !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это выглядит у вас вкратце:

```cs
myCar.PrintState();

...

    class Car    
    {
        ...

        public void PrintState()
        {
            textBox1.Text += Convert.ToString("{0} is going {1}MPH. " + petName + currSpeed + "\r\n");
        }
    }
```

Лучше работать с интерфейсом только в основном классе, а от `Car` просить текстовое представление информации:

```cs
textBox1.Text += $"{myCar.GetState()}\r\n";

...

    class Car    
    {
        ...

        public string GetState()
        {
            return $"{petName} is going {currSpeed}MPH.";
        }
    }
```

Если я правильно вспомнил, как `$-строками` в `C#` пользоваться.

Comment: Спасибо , сейчас попробую

Comment: Ошибок VS не показывает ,но почему то ничего не происходит

Comment: В смысле `button1_Click` не срабатывает? А он повешен на `Click` по форме? Мало его просто в коде описать, его надо в конструкторе формы указать в событии.

Comment: В событии все указанно. Форма после нажатия кнопки виснет . Возможно у меня код программы кривой и оно перегружает память. Но я пока не пойму где ошибка

Comment: ```1 <= 10``` :)

Comment: Спасибо большое всем !